# Typescript Pick Array not working as expected

Tags: typescript

I'm not sure why there is a problem if i use this line as array and how to fix it:

```
Pick<Author, PickedAuthorFields>[]
```

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=36&pc=1#code/PTAEFkEMEsDtQC4E8AOBTAzqSW6gCaQKQBGOaoAtKBgBYD2ArgDb4DkCoJFAxrZLADmafAFgAUMnSgAQvXoBrUAF5QAbwmhQ0fAC4aCAE5xBmxNATM0%20jEZNmAbtAzQSV-SXlWBZyIwQMhjZ2QhIAvhISUhQAgv6BKupmOsHGoeJasJAAttYGaabiEeISIKAAkrC0aIZoCCKgAGaG9NmIqJhNLW3ZMLBRHbLyCgBi0GisWKoKaEj0jUOKA9JxAfSGYxP4U6AzcwurgZHiZdFN66DCsDVEJqBoAB7oPPX4TXV8oLUYKPSwGBRmq1QDEAArlZaxFDQABKmDkigAPGZQdAeDN8AjRuNJvcHvVYNtFtithgADQotEYw7rTa4x4Eok0jY4okAH1AjEJaEacAaqi5%20B5fPwFPEAD5EhoMlxhvpUejEViyaAFRisXTtpKAGRJGVaPxrIKqqkiZmarAMtCErDm1lYAD8JsVzJVarN8Vp9vFAG0ALqgfSC4XXMQy4rFY6nTAIDCQ4kAdQstGZiRi0LhGCxiLYOjYKrYWVybFAHNz7HFUbAdCYrC4FCW4h4f1sssUSYCzIAjPosR2U57DFK2wp9GptHpQGwu-nsIP9D7xykpzPQGEA2E1xJm-9OJ528nmQAmXvDfup1Tj-ej9QT-TT2eGwIL8dFvJsKAPEvrtdbpstvcz0PQcAGZTwPTtB2Ha8xzvFdH3nUBF1AN970-WdlwfNcN1-MoAHdaCQe5DBaQwHQkIA).

If i use never instead of conditional type, than i have another problem with required author field.

[Sanbox 2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=36&ssc=89&pln=34&pc=65#code/PTAEFkEMEsDtQC4E8AOBTAzqSW6gCaQKQBGOaoAtKBgBYD2ArgDb4DkCoJFAxrZLADmafAFgAUMnSgAQvXoBrUAF5QAbwmhQ0fAC4aCAE5xBmxNATM0%20jEZNmAbtAzQSV-SXlWBZyIwQMhjZ2QhIAvhISUhQAgv6BKupmOsHGoeJasJAAttYGaabiEeISIKAAkrC0aIZoCCKgAGaG9NmIqJhNLW3ZMLBRHbLyCgBi0GisWKoKaEj0jUOKA9JxAfSGYxP4U6AzcwurgZHiZdFN66DCsDVEJqBoAB7oPPX4TXV8oLUYKPSwGBRmq1QDEAArlZaxFDQABKmDkigAPGZQdAeDN8AjRuNJvcHvVYNtFtithgADQotEYw7rTa4x4Eok0jY4omqa4OGoU8QAPkSGgyXGG%20lR6MRWLJoFFGKxdO2fIAZElBVo-GsglKqYjmZLpSJmXKMDyANoAXTMxWKx1OmAQGEhxIA6hZaMzEjFoXCMFjEWwdGxJWwsrk2KAAD6gP3sHkOrHOtb%20N2qD2w%20HDX3%20mMlE5gOhMVhcChLcQ8P62IWKeOu%20LrAAM%20jjLqYCCT6grCn0am0ekjAEZQ2FQMVS-9OJ5Ky7mQBmBvDKutrvjjttlJ9gPYGsa41d4N5NhQB7r1dsftD01Di9lADutCQ90MLUMAH4JEA)

Sandbox 3 with optional ? author had another problems...

[Sanbox 3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=39&ssc=24&pln=39&pc=41#code/PTAEFkEMEsDtQC4E8AOBTAzqSW6gCaQKQBGOaoAtKBgBYD2ArgDb4DkCoJFAxrZLADmafAFgAUMnSgAQvXoBrUAF5QAbwmhQ0fAC4aCAE5xBmxNATM0%20jEZNmAbtAzQSV-SXlWBZyIwQMhjZ2QhIAvhISUhQAgv6BKupmOsHGoeJasJAAttYGaabiEeISIKAAkrC0aIZoCCKgAGaG9NmIqJhNLW3ZMLBRHbLyCgBi0GisWKoKaEj0jUOKA9JxAfSGYxP4U6AzcwurgZHiZdFN66DCsDVEJqBoAB7oPPX4TXV8oLUYKPSwGBRmq1QDEAArlZaxFDQABKmDkigAPGZQdAeDN8AjRuNJvcHvVYNtFtithgADQotEYw7rTa4x4Eok0jY4omqa4OGoU8QAPkSGgyXGG%20lR6MRWLJoFFGKxdO2fIAZElBVo-GtDAB%20EVUxHMyXSkTMuUYHkAbQAumZisVjqdMAgMJDiQB1Cy0ZmJGLQuEYLGItg6NiSthZXJsUAAH1AAfYPKdWNda38HtUXth8OG-sDcZKJzAdCYrC4FCW4h4f1sQsUifd8XWAAZ9Am3UwECn1FWFPo1No9NGAIzhsKgYrl-6cTzVt3MgDMTeGNfbPcnXY7KQHQewdaCoFNPdDeTYUAem-XbEHI-NI%20vZQA7rQkPdDC1Nbb8wwWG9uE%20XxIx5WV0XbcABZ5ynJM223flO27Xt9HPTc1UCfQ91AA94OPU8%20wQy9r2HP8KwnBdp23ABWMCFCA9VoJXWCzwvYdiiAA)

This ApiResBook generic type is needed for many pages that will make requests to api with different expected output fields based on request.

Maybe there is alternative approach, i can change shape of object if needed.

```
// Main types as in database - should't be changed
type Book = {
  id: string
  title: string
  visible: boolean
  author: string
}

type Author = {
  id: string
  name: string
}

// Inhereted from types from main
type BookFields = keyof Book
type AuthorFields = keyof Author

// type for generating expected fetch response from API
type ApiResBook<
  PickedBookFields extends BookFields,
  PickedAuthorFields extends AuthorFields | undefined = undefined,
> = {
  book: Pick<Book, PickedBookFields> & {
    author: PickedAuthorFields extends AuthorFields ? Pick<Author, PickedAuthorFields>[] : undefined
  }
}

// tests
type BookWithAuthor = ApiResBook<'id', 'name' | 'id'>

// should be ok
const bookWithAuthor1: BookWithAuthor = { book: { id: '1', author: [{ id: '1' }] } }
const bookWithAuthor2: BookWithAuthor = { book: { id: '1', author: [{ name: 'Max' }] } }
const bookWithAuthor3: BookWithAuthor = { book: { id: '1', author: [{ name: 'Max', id: '1' }] } } // why error?
```

Comment: That's because conditional type is distributed over union type. You get `author: Pick<Author, "id">[] | Pick<Author, "name">[]` so only one of props picked. Do you really need to allow `undefined` as a `PickedAuthorFields` ?

Comment: If there is a way to do it like this: type BookWithAuthor = ApiResBook<'id'> // only book, without author prop, than no.

Comment: @AlekseyL. is right but if we remove the condition we will get `author: Pick<Author, PickedAuthorFields>[]` what will allow only objects with all fields, so partial objects like in two first examples will be failing. Only third would be ok

Comment: It's fine, but there is another problem: added another link in example.

Comment: Just ` author?` will not be enough? http://shorturl.at/gioJY

Comment: @MaciejSikora i'm not sure what are you saying

Comment: Link http://shorturl.at/gioJY, the quetsion is can we have `author` as optional prop

Comment: @MaciejSikora than there is another problems: shorturl.at/uJK37

Comment: @RTW I'd split utility types into two. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9nA1lAvFA3gWAFBSgSwBMAuKAZ2ACd8A7Acxz2H2ABsJSLr7GoA3fGXwAjdqWEJ2AQxq8pAV2AALOJU5VaDbAF8coSFACCilZVQZeRddy14aUgLYdyGnjr3ho8JADF8EVkIyc0QIEDgAM1gERA8DY2VVPwCgkLDIoxNVOOhDMHwAJQgyb0QAeRpWEAAeGCgIAA9gCBpU0uTAsgA+c3QoCSRSAAV8AGNEWpiAGlge3Wx9XPyikpja+qaWtpiOoJnDDebW4ITTXe7zPMLi0oqq2p6AMgtcfpjSLFe8BUS1KBHxtVTqp9l0ANoAXV483mOSgAHUWEpgWY0FcVqVqgByIhYmZY+xOLFQAA+UBxhCxXThiMSihRl2WNxidxqFKpOBwozgNAo-VItJU9KyqIwb0GYqs5IAjMTtFB5tzecB+lIBUiGWg+gNEB8CCQZXioD9TKQwX1Cc4sQBZKQNI1SrGyhUQhUKnBAA)

Comment: @AlekseyL.i was hopeful for one, but if there is no other way, that you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a while to figurate out but I think this is the solution:

```
type Book = {
  id: string
  title: string
  visible: boolean
  author: string
}

type Author = {
  id: string
  name: string
}

// Inhereted from types from main
type BookFields = keyof Book
type AuthorFields = keyof Author

// type for generating expected fetch response from API
type ApiResBook<
  PickedBookFields extends BookFields,
  PickedAuthorFields extends AuthorFields | null = null,
  AuthorObj = {author: Pick<Author, Exclude<PickedAuthorFields, null>>[]}
> = {
    book: Pick<Book, PickedBookFields> & (PickedAuthorFields extends null ? {} : AuthorObj)
}


// tests
type BookWithAuthor = ApiResBook<'id', 'name' | 'id'>
type BookWithoutAuthor = ApiResBook<'id'>

// should be ok
const bookWithAuthor0: BookWithoutAuthor = { book: { id: '1' } }
const bookWithAuthor3: BookWithAuthor = { book: { id: '1', author: [{ id: '1', name: 'Max' }] } }
```

PS. null can be replaced by undefined or any other unit type